# Center map on marker with Google-Maps-for-Rails and Rails 4

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I am using [Google-Maps-for-Rails](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails) on my application. My `house` object got a `latitude` and `longitude` attribute. My controller puts this stuff into an array and passes it to the javascript in my view:

```
def show
  @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@house) do |house, marker|
    marker.lat house.latitude
    marker.lng house.longitude
  end
end
```

The view looks like this:

```
<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
    markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
    handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
    handler.fitMapToBounds();
    handler.getMap().setZoom(10);
  });
</script>
```

Now it works totally fine. But on the inital map view my marker is always in the top-left corner. I want it to be in the middle of the map obviously.

What I tried it adding this line to the script which didn't really do anything:

```
handler.map.centerOn({ lat: markers[0].lat, lng: markers[0].lng });
```

What do I have to do to get the marker in the middle?

EDIT:
Okay, thanks to Zsolt I figured out that the inactivity of the tab when the map is loaded causes the problem. What I am trying to do now is recenter the map as soon as the tab is clicked by a user. Since my javascript is really bad I will need some assistance on this. That's what I got til now:

```
$('#tab_location').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  var myLatlng = {lat: gon.lat, lng: gon.lng};
  var map = document.getElementById('map');
  map.setCenter(myLatlng);
});
```

As you see I am using *gon* to get the right coordinates to the javascript. Catching the coordinates is working well but the rest will cause this error:

```
TypeError: a is undefined
```

*a* is some kind of variable inside the google maps script.

Answer (score 0):

I have very similar problem (marker cluster in top left). The gem's author suggested:

> "You should create the map after its div is made visible"

[here](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/issues/520)

Hope this helps you, I am a noob with JS. If you figure out the solution please let me know!

Comment: Thanks mate! Seems to be right but my javascript is pretty bad. Posted my idea in the mainpost but it's not working yet!